# Is there any way to set Anaconda autocompletion in Sublime Text without pressing the tab key?

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I'm using SublimeText3 with Anaconda. I'm wondering if there is any way to pop up Anaconda auto-completion without any key. I tried to use SublimeCodeIntel and CodeComplice and was impressed with their autocompletion. But I had a hard time with configuration and its errors and now I'm trying Anaconda. It seems like it's really working well but I think I would be more happy if it automatically showed autocomplete suggestions since my little finger is twisted from birth and I'm not so good at pressing the tab key :) Could anyone tell me if it's possible or any alternative idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For me it works by using:

```js
{
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
}
```

in sublime user settings. Then I get autocompletion suggestions automatically without pressing anything. I then push tab to commit.

Answer (score 1):

Open your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**) and add the following setting:

```js
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source, text.html"
    }
]
```

Now, every time you press `.`, a popup showing all of the possible methods/attributes will show. Also, if you have the following setting:

```js
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false
```

you can just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select your desired completion option instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! It helps me :) So, there seems to be no auto pop up.